# Highcharts Column chart Series data formatting change

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple column chart where the yAxis series data contains numeric strings in the millions and tens of millions. The chart therefore displays the graph numbers like this: "12.5M"(on the side of the grid) and in the points tooltip it is being displayed with a decimal point at the end. How do I make the data be shown in the thousands with commas? Will the chart be adjusted automatically to display more grid lines and raise the columns higher? Thanks a lot in advance.
I would have added an image, however it seems that that requires more reputation points. Sorry. Here's a link to it [Screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8100/WbTuic.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can change the formatting of the axis labels by setting your own format with the formatter function

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter

2) you can change the number of ticks by setting a tickInterval or tickPixel interval setting

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPixelInterval

3) You can change how much extra space is added at the top/how many ticks there are, in part, by setting the maxPadding setting to 0

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding

When you have a small chart like the one you posted, Highcharts will often have trouble adapting its normal tick pattern, and you will often end up with just a min and max tick by default.

It's pretty easy to work these setting to get what you need though.